# What method do you use a lot when controlling p4 command with Python?

Tags: python, pyqt, perforce

What method do you use a lot when controlling p4 command with Python?

1. Use p4 module
2. Control p4 command using subprocess ("p4 change")

I'm currently creating tool the second method

Comment: Use the p4python module if you can IMO.  If nothing else, doing anything involve specs is *much* easier with p4python because the spec gets turned into a dictionary object automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the simplest way to translate from command line to P4Python is the `p4.run()` command. You just pass in the command you want to run as the first argument and then add each P4 argument after that.

For example, in the terminal:

`p4 changes`

In Python would be:

`p4.run("changes")`

Terminal:

`p4 describe 153`

Python:

`p4.run("describe", 153)`

So a super simple example of just printing the results of p4 changes would be something like this:

```
from P4 import P4
p4 = P4()
p4.connect()
changelists = p4.run("changes")
print(changelists)
p4.disconnect()
```

There are other ways to run certain commands and some extra steps for things like submitting changelists so be sure to check the documentation: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4python/Content/P4Python/python.p4.html#Instance_Methods_..39

Hopefully this helps you get started!

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen the link you told me before.

Comment: You can also do `p4.run_changes()`, or any other command (there's some `getattr` magic that turns any `run_*` method into a call to `run(*)`).

Comment: @Samwise
Thanks a lot, After modifying pyqt ui, I will change command method to use p4 module